# Shrinking Reluctant Log Files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several SQL Server 2008 databases with transaction logs which have gotten out of hand and filled the drive. One of these logs was 68gb *yikes*.

I know better than to kill off my backup chain by truncating the log but when I do a shrink alone, on several of the databases I get no reclamation of space whatsoever and on those that I do, the amount is negligible. I have verified that the client is running t-log backups hourly and that these have succeeded for the last several weeks.

Obviously I'm missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction or am I just stuck with having to manually truncate and pray nothing happens in the meantime?

Comment: How are you performing "a shrink alone"? Can you show the syntax you used and when you ran these commands?

Comment: My answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18789/2718) may be of interest, in addition to Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those exceptions where it's probably okay to execute a `DBCC SHRINKFILE`. The log file is most likely this large not because of what is going on right now but because there was a time when hourly transaction logs were *not* being run (or you had an exceptionally large transaction that ran between or across log backups). I'm not sure where the misconception comes from, but backing up the log does *not* shrink the file for you, it only frees up space within the file.

You can perform a one-time operation like this without interfering with the log chain (or having to "hope" that "nothing happens in the meantime"), preferably right after a log backup has completed successfully:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(yourdb_log, 4000);
```

This should shrink the file to ~4 GB, which hopefully is plenty of room to accommodate your hourly transactions. You may want to pick a different size, I'm not sure...

If this command doesn't shrink the file as much as you expect, you can check why the log modification may be blocked using:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE name = N'yourdb';
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron...I had been doing this through the GUI. The script worked perfect.

Comment: Yeah don't use the UI for this. It does silly things.